# Как в массиве в названии ключа разрешить любые числа?

Tags: php, laravel

Всем привет подскажите пожалуйста, у меня есть ларавелевский валидатор messages в котором в ключе массива мне необходимо разрешить любое число. Знаю что если поставить * то все что после нее будет все будет проходить. Но можно ли как то только числа сделать?

```html
 public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'attributes.*.required' => 'Необходимо выбрать атрибут',
        ];
    }
```

то есть вот что типа такого

```html
 public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'attributes.[0-9].required' => 'Необходимо выбрать атрибут',
        ];
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете создать свой `Rule` класс для валидации и проверить там ключей входного массива

```
<?php

namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

class IntegerArrayKeys implements Rule
{

    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        return is_array($value) && count(array_filter(array_keys($value), 'is_string')) === 0;
    }

    public function message()
    {
        return 'Ключ массива должен быть числовым';
    }
}
```